# How to compare grouped duplicate rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a dataset where samples/genes are grouped by matching IDs. I am trying to compare the groups of matched IDs.

For example I have:

```
ID      Gene    Score
1:10    Gene1    0.8
1:10    Gene1    0.78
1:10    Gene4    0.6
2:20    Gene5    0.1
2:20    Gene6    0.7
3:30    Gene7    0.4
3:30    Gene8    0.6  
3:30    Gene8    0.5
```

I am trying to find various stats like the percentage of matching ID groups which have more than 1 gene with a >0.7 score in their group (from my example data this would be 33.3% of matching ID groups have  that) or how many groups have a 0.7 scored gene and a 0.1 scored gene present under the same matched ID (also 33.3% of groups in the example).

I have been trying to use `duplicated()` and `filter()` to start this but beyond these I'm not sure what functions to try, any advice on functions to try would be appreciated.

Input data:

```
structure(list(ID = c("1:10", "1:10", "1:10", "2:20", "2:20", 
"3:30", "3:30", "3:30"), Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene4", 
"Gene5", "Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", "Gene8"), Score = c(0.8, 
0.78, 0.6, 0.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of completeness and because the question has a `data.table` tag:

```
ds[, any(Score > 0.7), by = .(ID)][, sum(V1)/length(V1)]
```

> ```
> [1] 0.3333333
> ```

```
ds[, any(Score == 0.7 | Score == 0.1), by = .(ID)][, sum(V1)/length(V1)]
```

or

```
ds[, any(Score %in% c(0.1, 0.7)), by = .(ID)][, sum(V1)/length(V1)]
```

> ```
> [1] 0.3333333
> ```

In order to verify the results are correct we can integrate a `print()` statement in the *chained* `data.table` expressions:

```
ds[, any(Score > 0.7), by = .(ID)][, print(.SD)][, sum(V1)/length(V1)]
```

> ```
>      ID    V1
> 1: 1:10  TRUE
> 2: 2:20 FALSE
> 3: 3:30 FALSE
> [1] 0.3333333
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
ds <- structure(list(ID = c("1:10", "1:10", "1:10", "2:20", "2:20", 
"3:30", "3:30", "3:30"), Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene4", 
"Gene5", "Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", "Gene8"), Score = c(0.8, 
0.78, 0.6, 0.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library("dplyr")

df <- structure(list(ID = c("1:10", "1:10", "1:10", "2:20", "2:20", 
"3:30", "3:30", "3:30"), Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene4", 
"Gene5", "Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", "Gene8"), Score = c(0.8, 
0.78, 0.6, 0.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

ID group has more than one gene with a score > 0.7

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(cond = sum(Score > 0.7) > 1) %>%
  replace_na(list(cond = FALSE)) %>%
  summarize(frac = sum(cond) / n())

# A tibble: 1 x 1
   frac
  <dbl>
1 0.333
```

ID group has at least one gene with a score of 0.7, and at least one with 0.1

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID, Gene) %>%
  summarize(cond = any(Score %in% c(0.1, 0.7))) %>%
  replace_na(list(cond = FALSE)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(cond = any(cond)) %>%
  summarize(frac = sum(cond) / n())

# A tibble: 1 x 1
   frac
  <dbl>
1 0.333
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks very clear and easy for me to use. I've tried it on my real data and it comes back with NA's for both and a message: ```summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)``` - is there something else I might need to do for my real data?

Comment: What does your real data look like compared to the example data?

Comment: Some rows in the column are NA and don't have a score, this is the only difference, besides 2 other extra columns making up the dataset

Comment: Managed to solve my NAs and this works now - thanks for your reply